# Объединить общие категории

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. У меня есть  категории :

```
array(
    'Кузов/Двери/Дверь багажника',
    'Кузов/Двери/Ручка двери наружная',
    'Кузов/Двери/Дверь',
);
```

Первые родители есть у них общие. Как можно сделать так, чтобы получить из этих категорий  одну с вложенностью  ? (можно просто объяснить логику, без примера)

```
Кузов
  Двери 
    Дверь багажника
    Ручка двери наружная
    Дверь
```

Comment: А категории вы эти где и как храните?

Comment: нигде. Мне нужно из этого списка сформировать (список будет больше) . Полагаю explode сначала будет действовать

Comment: а хранить где будете потом? Для чего это? Можете подробнее описать?

Comment: нигде хранить не буду. Нигде не применяется.  Мне нужно логику действий понять просто . Нужно из списка этого сделать вложенность

Comment: Пересортировать массив в новый и вывести данные.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov продемонстрируйте

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian если длина цепочки категорий всегда одинаковая, то проблем нет. А вот если нет... Так что с количеством категорий в цепочке?

Comment: Автор, что с количеством категорий в цепочке?

Comment: длина различна в цепочки  может быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно собрать массив, а затем уже выводить как угодно, работает с любой вложенностью:

```
$ar = array(
    'Кузов/Двери/Дверь багажника',
    'Кузов/Двери/Ручка двери наружная',
    'Другой/Двери/Дверь',
    'Другой/Двери/Красные/Красная',
);

$result = [];

foreach($ar as $section) {
    $tmp = &$result;

    foreach(explode('/', $section) as $subsection) {
        $tmp = &$tmp[$subsection];
        $last = $subsection;
    }

   $tmp = $subsection;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: спасибо. ТО что надо !

Answer (score -2):

Вот вариант:

```html
$ar = array(
  'Кузов/Двери/Дверь багажника',
  'Кузов/Двери/Ручка двери наружная',
  'Кузов/Лудки/Ручка двери наружная',
  'Кузов/Двери/Ручка двери наружная',
  'Другой/Двери/Дверь',
);

foreach ($ar as $value) {
  $exp = explode("/", $value);
  $new_ar[$exp[0]][$exp[1]][] = $exp;
}


foreach ($new_ar as $key => $value) {
  echo "<h1>$key</h1>";
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($value);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: привет землякам :)

К сожалению, получил не тот результат, который хотел . Должна быть вложенность массивов, как я полагаю, чтобы выстраивать цепочки категорий . Возможно что-то неверно доношу до вас